# How to properly format url path in AWS ELB path rule condition (accented characters)

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-elb

I'm trying to insert a path rule condition, inside the AWS ELB, redirecting from an old document directory to a new one.
The problem is with the name of the file itself. It contains accented characters but AWS does not accept accented characters in the path condition.
From AWS documentation only the following characters are allowed:

- A-Z, a-z, 0-9
- _ - . $ / ~ " ' @ : +
- & (using &)
- *(matches 0 or more characters)
- ? (matches exactly 1 character)

The word I'm trying to encode is "fumé". The problem is the character "é", which can't be written as %c3%a9.
I also tried with "fum?" but of course, it didn't work.

How can I achieve the expected behavior?